# serializing array when nested with other attributes in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have a ruby (2.4.0p0) rails (5.0.2) controller from which I wish to return a json result containing a list of Thing objects as well as some high level info (such as next and previous from Kaminari paging).

Consider a Thing with an association to Owner. Thing has a owner_id attribute.

For @things = Thing.page(1).per(2) I will be able to use

render json: @things

and get;

```
[
    { "id": 1, "owner_id": 1, "name": "thing1" },
    { "id": 2, "owner_id": 1, "name": "thing2" }
]
```

Good.  If I then create a serializer called ThingSerializer.rb and define owner such that it adds "owner":"CatInHat" instead of "owner_id":1
This works as well;

```
[
    { "id": 1, "owner": "CatInHat", "name": "thing1" },
    { "id": 2, "owner": "CatInHat", "name": "thing2" }
]
```

This is good, but, my problem comes when I want to add higher level data and label the list as "results" such as when I try;

render json: { next:"some_url_link",previous:"some_other_url_link", results: @bags}

I'd like to get;

```
{ "next":some_url_link,
    "prev":some_other_url_link,
    "results":[ { "id": 1, "owner": "CatInHat", "name": "thing1" }, { "id": 2, "owner": "CatInHat", "name": "thing2" } ]
}
```

What I get is nearly the above but with "owner_id":1 instead of "owner":"CatInHat" - my serializer does not seem to be used when I label and nest my list of things.  What is the appropriate way to use my serializer and get this output?

If I create config/initializers/active_model_serializers.rb and add 
    ActiveModel::Serializer.config.adapter = :json_api
It gives me an api which is similar but I don't know if it can be customized to fit the spec I need above.

thank you for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the serialization logic in `render json: ...` only kicks in if the attribute is an ActiveRecord object or an array of ActiveRecord objects. Since you are giving it a hash, it will not inspect the individual attributes and recursively apply the serializers.

You can try manually applying `ThingSerializer`:

```
render json: {
  next: ...,
  prev: ...,
  results: @things.map { |thing|
    ThingSerializer.new(thing).attributes
  },
}
```

Comment: I just tried that and now I'm trying to track down the error ; undefined method `read_attribute_for_serialization'

Comment: I haven't tested the code, so it might not work. The one thing that's certain though is that you have to invoke the serializer manually somehow.

Comment: Yes, sounds reasonable.  I'll keep trying a few things in that direction.  thanks

Comment: Serializers might not be able to handle entire arrays of elements. Updated the example with a version that serializes it one by one.

Comment: That works!  The serialization did handle the array when it was the only thing being rendered, e.g my first result above with just 'render json: @things' but it seems to be unable to deal with an array when it is embedded deeper...  thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm too new to stack overflow (though lurking for many years) to give you any points (it recorded but does not show my points) but I did accept the answer.